# what is diff b/w String & StringBuilder object creation in terms of assigning reference to it's object?

Tags: java, string

This is a sample code, I am confused at it's behavior.

```
public class RefCheckForStrings {

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("abc");
        sb.append("def");     //error  syntax error
        //System.out.println(sb);
        String s="abc";
        s.concat("def");     //error  syntax error
        //System.out.println(s);*/

        public static void set(){
            String s="abc";
            s.concat("def");
            System.out.println(s);    // prints  abc
                String str=s.concat("def");
                System.out.println(str);   //  prints abcdef
            final StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("abc");
            sb.append("def");
            System.out.println(sb);    //prints abcdef
        }
```

1. why there is syntax error while modifying object in class ? I think it's same reason as System.out.print() also not working there... But i could not understand it fully through google search... Please explain or give a reference to get it clear..
2. In case of String object, if we modify it, Does the reference point to a new object(The modified one created as another object) & for StringBuilder, does the reference points the same object(the same object has the modification)...  I can think these two answer is YES, and that is basic difference b/w String& StringBilder. Am i correct or missing any concepts of String....   Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's what Java decided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do those operations as a part of a method...

```
public class RefCheckForStrings {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("abc");
        sb.append("def");     // You can do this only inside a method 
        //System.out.println(sb);
        String s="abc";
        s.concat("def");     // You can do this only inside a method 
        //System.out.println(s);*/
}
```

Possibly as below... to take an example of doing these in a constructor

```
public class RefCheckForStrings {

        StringBuilder sb;
        String s;

       public RefCheckForStrings()
       {
               sb=new StringBuilder("abc");
               s = "abc";
               sb.append("def"); 
                s.concat("def");
       }
}
```

There is another way of doing the same thing without using a method in Java 7... it is as shown below...

```
public class RefCheckForStrings {

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("abc");
    {
        sb.append("def");  
        System.out.println(sb);   
    }
    String s="abc";
    {
        s.concat("def");    
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

To answer your second question... Strings are immutable, in other words. Once you assign address of a string to a variable, the string located in that address cannot be changed. if you do s.concat() when s is a string, a new string will be created in memory which is a concatenated form. But address of s doesn't directly change. So, you have explicitly tell s.concat() as `s = s.concat("abc");`. Where as the way String builders are developed, they can be directly changed in the location where they are created without having to create a new copy in the memory. So they are mutable and don't have to assign any reference back to the string builder object.

If you create a string s and if you assume the string "abc" is assigned to it, assume "abc" is stored at address 1001 if you do s+"def" the resulting string may be stored at address 2001, but s will still be pointing to 1001. instead if you do s = s + "def", the location of where s is pointed to will also change, so now s is pointing to 2001. The string "abc" will still be located at 1001 and it will be cleaned by garbage collector if not used for some time.

Comment: I am confused as we say String is immutable, Does it mean String class is final or the String object is final or both?

Comment: Hello Pankaj, String class being final has nothing to do with this being immutable. If you create a string s and if you assume the string "abc" is assigned to it, assume "abc" is stored at address 1001 if you do s+"def" the resulting string may be stored at address 2001, but s will still be pointing to 1001. instead if you do s = s + "def", the location of where s is pointed to will also change, so now s is pointing to 2001. The string "abc" will still be located at 1001 and it will be cleaned by garbage collector if not used for some time. let me know if you still have doubt regarding this.

Comment: Also, `String` being final is important for immutability. It means that one cannot just subclass `String` and override its methods to make it mutable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Class body cannot have statements which are not assignments. To do that, you have to put them in blocks:

   ```
   public class RefCheckForStrings {

       StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("abc");
       {
           sb.append("def");
           System.out.println(sb);
       } 
       String s="abc";
       {
           s.concat("def");
           System.out.println(s);
       }
   }
   ```
2. `String`s are immutable in java. It means that you cannot change their values. Calling `"abc".concat("def")` returns a new `String` that you'll have to assign to a new variable to capture it.

   ```
   String ad = "abc".concat("def");
   ```

   Whereas `StringBuilder`s are mutable so calling `concat` on them changes their value in-place.

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
   sb.concat("def");
   // value in sb is now "abcdef"
   ```

Comment: So if we do String s="abc";s.concat("def);->it creates other object "abcdef" but it has no one to reference, so it's lost. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

1. There's a syntax error because that's not where those statements go.
2. Strings are immutable. Any method that "modifies" the String object is in fact returning a *new* String object so you need to reassign it to the variable. The StringBuilder isn't immutable, methods that modify it (`append` for example) don't return a new StringBuilder object.